# Python convert dictionary where keys have multiple values into list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a dictionary into a list of tuples. I see that there are lots of similar posts on here, but I didn't see any with the same format that I am looking for. For example, I may be given the following as a dict:

```
{"A": ["B", "C", "D"], "B":["D"], "C":[], "D":["A"]}
```

And I want the output to look like a list with elements such as...

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A", 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'A')]
```

where the key is set with the corresponding values as their own tuples.

So for the following, I am writing the function find_par where it takes in a dict, and 2 strings such as "A" and "D". Ultimately I'm what this function does is try to find the parent node of the vert parameter. I figured if I can get a list, I can loop over the list continuously checking the 2nd element and once it matches vert, I can return the first element because that would be the parent. Otherwise I would return nothing.

```
def find_par(tree, root, vert):

if root == vert:
    return []
else:
    for key, value in tree.items():
        temp = [key,value]
        print (temp)
```

This code produces the following output with the dict `{"A": ["B", "C"], "B":["D"], "C":[], "D":[]}` provided:

```
['A', ['B', 'C']]
['B', ['D']]
['C', []]
['D', []]
```

Again, it should look like `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D'),...]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the items in the sub-list in each dict value (given your dict stored as variable `d`):

```
[(k, i) for k, l in d.items() for i in l]
```

This returns:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
dict1 = {"A": ["B", "C"], "B":["D"], "C":[], "D":[]}

for key, values in dict1.items():
    for i in values:
        print([key,i])

 #prints ['A', 'B'],['A', 'C'],['B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stored your dict as variable z.

```
[(a, b) for a in z for b in z[a]]
```

Below I'll explain how this nesting of list comprehension works:

You're taking every key in the dictionary with 
`for a in z` and matching it with every value in the list associated with z[a] using `for b in z[a]`.  You can see at the beginning of the statement I create a tuple.